# php show array value for variable key

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make a site multi lingual. by building a language dictionary array ( if it is not the best way please don't hesitate to let me know )

```
$fr=array();

$fr['hello']="Bonjour";
```

I would like to make a function that does the following :

for every word and language  `function ( $word ="hello",$language="fr")`

it would return the right value. So far the way I am doing isn't working

```
echo $$language[$word];
```

any ideas?
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, variables are local to a function. If your dictionary arrays are global, you need to declare them as global, but since the names are variable, you have to access them via [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php):

```
function foo($word, $language) {
  echo $GLOBALS[$language][$word];
}
```

As for a better way, you might want to use just one multi-dimensional array instead of creating one variable for each language:

```
$dict = array();
$dict['fr']['hello'] = 'Bonjour';

function foo($word, $language) {
  global $dict;
  echo $dict[$language][$word];
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about avoiding queries in multi dimensional arrays due to the load ... or is it not a big deal in this case? the way my function looks is like this : function translator_fw($word, $language="en"){
 

 require_once('lib/languages/'.$language.'.php');

 $arr=$$language;

 return $arr[$word];
}  would love to get your feedback . Thanks

Comment: @salmane: Multi-dimensional arrays aren't going to add any noticeable overhead (if any at all) to your program.

Comment: thank you. would recommend a Database approach all together? or is this multi dimensional array the best approach? thanks again

Comment: @salmane: Database queries might be too expensive just to build a multi-lingual user interface. Your current way of using include files for each language is fine and you can use it together with the multi-dimensional array idea.

Answer (score 3):

A few things to mention here...

1. I would recommend using actual "locales" (a [language code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639) plus [country code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)) to reference your languages rather than your two letter country code.  Your example includes "fr" for French.  Typical convention is to use locale names instead.  For example fr_FR for French (France) and fr_CA for French (Canadien).  Language can very greatly based on country (if you're a native US English speaker and take a trip to Australia, you'll understand what I'm talking about).
2. Depending on the size of your site, you probably don't want to keep this as a PHP dictionary/assoc array.  There are lots of options here (putting translations in a database, shared memory, etc.).  If you do keep it in PHP memory, [opcode caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator) would be a great idea and is relatively easy to setup.  I would encourage you to look at how other frameworks achieve this (and ideally maybe use an existing framework to achieve this).
3. You mention translating "words".  Generally, when internationalizing a site, you want to translate phrases.  Translating words and then gluing them together typically results in poor translations.
4. If you do stick with the dict route, I would highly encourage you to drop the dynamic interpretation of the the variable name/language name in favor of a nested associative array.  For example `$dict['fr_FR']['hello'] = 'bonjour';`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using a single (nested) array

```
$strings = array(
    "french" => array(
        "stringID" => "foobar"
    )
);

echo( $strings["french"]["stringID"] );
```

If you are not utilising a database I would highly recommend looking into this. MySQL and PostgreSQL tend to be popular choices for independent and small development shops.

Answer (score 0):

$$language[$word] didn't work

the work around was

$arr=$$language;

$arr[$word];

Comment: but this would not fix the variable scope issue.